# How can I reference UWP classes in PowerShell

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, uwp

I want to use a data type from a Universal Windows Platform library, how can I reference the containing namespace or assembly in PowerShell?

For example, I want to use the [`Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject) to parse me some json.

Had this been a regular .NET class, I would have done something like

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Windows.Data.Json
$jsonObject = [Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject]::Parse('{data:["powershell","rocks"]}')
```

But this strategy fails me with:

```
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'Windows.Data.Json' could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -AssemblyName Windows.Data.Json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Windows.Data.Json:String) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Now, it could be that I'm simply wrong in assuming that the assembly for the `Windows.Data.Json` namespace is `Windows.Data.Json.dll`, but the API reference does not actually seem to contain any references to containing files, leading me to believe that a dll file is actually not what I should be looking for.

I assume UWP has it's own cool GAC-like store from which I can load shared libraries, I simply just don't know how.

So basically my question is, **how can I load a UWP shared library into PowerShell, and how should I reference UWP type literals?**

Running PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10 (build 1703)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shortly after posting this question, I stumbled on [the GitHub repo for BurntToast](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast/blob/c0abfdac392ace8dd7c28bb0cd46842024aaaf30/BurntToast/Public/Submit-BTNotification.ps1), a module that allows raising UWP Toast Notifications from PowerShell, and it references the WinRT ToastNotificationManager type like this:

```
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
```

So, it looks like the syntax I'm after for UWP classes is:

```
[<class name>,<namespace>,ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
```

With this in mind, I tried it with the example I gave in the question and lo and behold:

```
PS C:\> $jsonObjectClass = [Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject,Windows.Data.Json,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
PS C:\> $jsonObject = $jsonObjectClass::Parse('{"data":["powershell","rocks"]}')
PS C:\> $jsonObject

Key  Value                 
---  -----                 
data ["powershell","rocks"]
```

After referencing the type name once, I seem to be able to use the class name in a type literal without qualifying it as well:

```
[Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject]::Parse("{}") # works without throwing errors now
```

Still very keen to find any documentation on this though

Comment: Would you accept a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2012/05/27/loading-winrt-types-via-reflection-in-windows-8/)?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Fine reference, feel free to add an answer outlining the meaning of the GetType/TypeInfo parameter

Comment: Nicely done. Strangely, the middle string can be _any_ nonempty string. Unfortunately, the technique doesn't seem to work in PowerShell Core, and the underlying assembly, `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.winmd`, cannot be loaded directly. The blog-post link is dead now, but here's an archived copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20190119013259/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2012/05/27/loading-winrt-types-via-reflection-in-windows-8/